# DART algorithm implementation. Converting mathematical notation to pseudocode

Tags: machine-learning, regression, decision-trees, boosting, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I am learning how DART algorithm (https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01866) works and I want to implement it in C#

I have the algorithm's description in mathematical notation and I don't understand most of it. I want to convert it to pseudocode, preferably C style. Many thanks.

I am refering to this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01866.pdf

Image from the article:

[image: DART mathematical notation]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not familiar with the DART algorithm, but I thought it might be a good task for ChatGPT, so I took the Latex source of the article you linked, and asked it to generate C# code for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Node
{
    public double X;  // Input feature value
    public double Y;  // Output label value
}

public class Tree
{
    public List<Node> Nodes;  // List of nodes in the tree
}

public class DARTAlgorithm
{
    public const double Pdrop = 0.2;  // Probability of dropping a tree
    
    // Trains an ensemble of decision trees on the given dataset
    public List<Tree> Train(List<Node> dataset, int nTrees)
    {
        // Initialize the first tree with a single node at (0, 0)
        var S1 = new List<Node> { new Node { X = 0, Y = 0 } };
        var T1 = new Tree { Nodes = TrainTree(S1, dataset) };
        var M = new List<Tree> { T1 };  // Ensemble of trees
        
        for (int t = 2; t <= nTrees; t++)
        {
            // Randomly drop a subset of trees from the ensemble
            var D = M.Where(t => new Random().NextDouble() < Pdrop).ToList();
            if (!D.Any()) D.Add(M[new Random().Next(M.Count)]);
            var M_hat = M.Except(D).ToList();
            
            // Construct a new dataset S_t for training the next tree
            var S_t = new List<Node>();
            foreach (var x in dataset)
            {
                // Compute the negative gradient of the loss function
                // with respect to the output label for this input
                var y_hat = Predict(M_hat, x);  // Predict the output for the input x
                S_t.Add(new Node { X = x.X, Y = y_hat - x.Y });
            }
            
            // Train the next tree on the new dataset S_t
            var T_t = new Tree { Nodes = TrainTree(S_t, dataset) };
            M.Add(T_t);  // Add the new tree to the ensemble
            
            // Scale the trees in D and replace them in M
            foreach (var tree in D)
            {
                M[M.IndexOf(tree)] = ScaleTree(tree, D.Count + 1);
            }
        }
        
        return M;
    }
    
    // Trains a decision tree on the given dataset
    private List<Node> TrainTree(List<Node> dataset, List<Node> fullDataset)
    {
        // TODO: Implement decision tree training algorithm
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    // Predicts the output label for the given input using the given ensemble of trees
    private double Predict(List<Tree> ensemble, Node x)
    {
        // TODO: Implement tree ensemble prediction algorithm
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    // Scales the given tree by the given scale factor
    private Tree ScaleTree(Tree tree, int scaleFactor)
    {
        // TODO: Implement tree scaling algorithm
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I don't know if it works, but it compiles.

I hesitated to publish this answer (both because I don't know if it is correct and because I myself think that people posting AI-generated answers is detrimental to the overall quality of SE sites). However, I think this is the kind of task where ChatGPT can be very useful and I wanted to illustrate this use and encourage readers to use AI tools to help themselves understand.

I will be happy to remove the answer if people think it is not appropriate here.